# Flutter searching for contacts in Hebrew (left-to-right) with whitespace is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to search for contacts that are saved in my local language(Not English).
For example, I have 2 words in my name. Let's say a b
When I search for "a" (first word) it is working fine but when I'll add "space" there to write another word, the contact list will return empty, even after every word of the space it'll get an empty list.
Here is the example of using the code:

```dart
ContactsService.getContacts(
withThumbnails: false,
photoHighResolution: false,
query: a b);
```

Note: "a b" I used as an example. In my case, it is my Hebrew language word.

Screenshot of adding the first word:

[image: screenshot of adding the first word]

Screenshot of Adding Space after one word:

[image: screenshot of Adding Space after one word]

Screenshot of adding letter space:

[image: screenshot of adding letter space]

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

When spacing, for instance in Hebrew, a Unicode character `\u200f` is added.

In order to check that your string contain `\u200f`, just copy the string from your `run terminal` to [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). As you can see there is a strange dot near the space.

[image: a strange dot example]

In that case, all you need to do is to remove the Unicode character with the above regex:

```
var searchName = val.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[\u200f]'), "");
```

A use-case on searching contacts by name:

```
List<Contact> tempContactList = List<Contact>();
contactList.forEach((contact) {
  if (contact.displayName != null){
    var searchName = val.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[\u200f]'), "");
    if(contact.displayName.contains(searchName)){
      tempContactList.add(contact);
    }
  }
});
```

Enjoy! :)